# No Dynos is running for Django web app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, web-hosting

I am working on a web app that i have made using Python, Django. After completed this app in development I have decided to host the app on Heroku so that other peoples will also visit my website to do so I signed up on Heroku and create a new app. I then pushed my app to heroku using git but whenever I visit url I get:

**Application error**
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

> heroku logs --tail

When I go to resource page of my app I realize that there is no dyno instance running.
I check the logs and I'm getting a H14 - No web processes running.Which suggest that my app has no dyno's indeed. I tried a lot of solution from internet and have searched all stack overflow questions related to this problem but my problem still not solved:

Here is the command in my **Procfile**:

```
web: gunicorn MyFirstWebsite.wsgi --log-file -
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
I am following this procedure https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem is solved because i made a mistake in Procfile and the mistake is that i made a Procfile with extension `.txt`. The Procfile is always a simple text file that is named `Procfile` without a file extension. For example, `Procfile.txt` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with "no dynos" error...
finally i found out the error was caused by a forgotten space between "--log-file" and the last "-" in Procfile